# writing a function that shows left associativity equals right associativity

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

i have been trying to write a function that shows that left association is the same as right association. basically meaning that (x, (y, z)) is the same as ((x, y), z), and vice versa, for this case. i have tried using let and in logic but that didnt work. so far i have

```
lAssociation :: (a, (b, c)) -> ((a, b), c)
lAssociation (a, b) = ((a, fst b), snd b)
```

but i get a parse error for some reason. I'm not sure what I am missing. I am new to haskell and want to understand so any help, suggestions, or advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: The code you have there should not give an error. Are you sure that you've pasted the right code in the question?

Answer (score 5):

The original signature was:

```
lAssociation :: ((a, b), c) -> (a, (b, c))
lAssociation (a, b) = ((a, fst b), snd b)
```

since you use [**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) and [**`snd :: (a, b) -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd), this thus means that `b` is a 2-tuple, and this thus means that the second item of the input type is a 2-tuple:

```
lAssociation :: (a, (b, c)) -> ((a, b), c)
lAssociation (a, b) = ((a, fst b), snd b)
```

I would however advise to use pattern matching over `fst` and `snd`, and thus work with:

```
lAssociation :: (a, (b, c)) -> ((a, b), c)
lAssociation (a, (b, c)) = -- …
```

Answer (score 2):

Your type and your implementation are mismatched.  What you have written is

```
lAssociation :: (a, (b, c)) -> ((a, b), c)
```